# SQUERY SALESFORCE

Tags: apex, soql

Hi Please find the Query as below i am not able to save this , kindly help me out.

```
sQuery = 'Select id,Investment_Capability_Reference__c,Investment_Strategy__c,Source__c,Rating__c,Asset_Class__c,Global_Fund_Code__c,Fund_Name__c,Account_Fund_Ratings__c,Account_Fund_Ratings__r.head_office__c, Account_Fund_Ratings__r.parent.Name FROM Investment_Capability__c WHERE Account_Fund_Ratings__c != Null AND Source__c = \''+On Panel+'\' AND Source__c= +'\''+On Panel - Buy+'\'';
```

giving error in saving.
Unrecognized symbol '', which is not a valid Apex identifier.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the error message (just copy and paste it verbatim, do not try to paraphrase it) as well as more of your code for context.

Comment: Added required detials thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside whether this should be a dynamic SOQL query at all (it doesn't look like it should be), your filters (the `WHERE` clause) are incorrectly trying to concatenate string literals.

That is, things like `Source__c = \''+On Panel+'\'` are wrong

The `+` operator on strings is used for concatenation, but `On Panel` isn't a variable. You meant for `On Panel` to be a *string literal*. Basic string concatenation looks something like `String combined = 'string one' + 'string two';`

Applying that to this particular filter would get you something like `Source__c =\'' + 'On Panel' + '\''`.
String concatenation, however, is mostly useful when you are trying to add the value of a variable into a string. In this case where you're just concatenating two string literals together, you're just making your life harder than it needs to be.

You don't need concatenation here at all, just keep it as a single string literal and escape the quotes around the filter value. E.g.
`Source__c = \'On Panel\'`

I'll leave fixing the rest of your query as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to know what you're trying to achieve. Based on what you posted, I assume the criteria you're trying to get is:

```sql
WHERE 
Account_Fund_Ratings__c != NULL 
AND Source__c = 'On Panel' 
AND Source__c = 'On Panel - Buy'
```

However, I'll callout **nothing** will ever *match* that as you're using `AND` to check equality for two *different* values for the *same* field `Source__c`.

Regrading your error, your syntax is off where you're trying to escape your quotes `'` and concatenate (`+`) strings. I don't know the context of how/where you're executing this, but you could store your strings in separate variables and [bind variables](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/use-bind-variables-and-aggregate-functions#:%7E:text=A%20bind%20variable%20is%20an,a%20placeholder%20in%20a%20method.) instead.

```apex
[rest of query...WHERE 
Account_Fund_Ratings__c != NULL 
AND Source__c = :panelValue
AND Source__c = :buyPanelValue];
```

Otherwise, you can properly escape your quotes and not use concatenation at all.

```sql
WHERE 
Account_Fund_Ratings__c != NULL 
AND Source__c = \'On Panel\'
AND Source__c = \'On Panel - Buy\'
```

Comment: Source cannot simultaneously be both values. It should be OR, or use IN.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to correct the where clause:

```
String sQuery = 'Select id,Investment_Capability_Reference__c,Investment_Strategy__c,Source__c,Rating__c,Asset_Class__c,Global_Fund_Code__c,Fund_Name__c, Account_Fund_Ratings__c,Account_Fund_Ratings__r.head_office__c, Account_Fund_Ratings__r.parent.Name FROM Investment_Capability__c WHERE Account_Fund_Ratings__c != Null AND Source__c = '+ '\'On Panel\'' + ' AND Source__c = ' + '\'On Panel - Buy\'';
```